# Hide "Submit for Approval" button until @future method completes

Tags: apex, trigger, force.com, future

I have complex logic running in the trigger which I want to move to asynchronous @future method. This logic is to update few fields on the record and there is a approval process which depends on these fields. If I move the logic to @future method; how can I not allow user to click on "Submit for Approval" button until that @future is complete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple options

1. Create a new page layout (remove the approval related list) and then create a new Record Type (Let's B) for it. Use a trigger to update the record type to **B**, once @future is complete update the record type back to master ( the original one).
2. Create a field (Let's say Future_Complete__c, default value FALSE). Add additional criteria in your Process (Future_Complete__c == TRUE). Once @future is complete update Future_Complete__c to TRUE.

Comment: Option 1 would be more useful, as it wouldn't confuse user.

Comment: Thank you @J Doe. I had already thought of this and it will work perfectly fine on the new record. But what happens if lets say on the edit of the record.

Comment: Let me provide steps-
1) During initial creation before future - record type is B. (This has no approval related list)
2) Once future completes- record type is changed to Master. (This has approval List)
3) What if user edits the record again before approval & changes some fields and saves. My future method will start again but the record type was already set to master. So, before future completes user can click on "Submit for Approval" button which should not be the case.

Comment: @TJD, You must use a combination of both the options to achieve this. Option2 should work well for insert/updates, but if you want to go with first option(for inserts), then have the field Future_Complete__c created anyway and update it to Future_Complete__c =TRUE from the future method on INSERT. For every edit, you should make this field Future_Complete__c =FALSE from the before trigger update. After this update, future method will run again and make Future_Complete__c =TRUE

Comment: Thanks @ShaliniMendu. I will try this but not sure if it is going to work since if I am calling future method from "after update"; I don't think it will access the changed value of the flag from "Before update" trigger since the values are not yet committed to salesforce.

Comment: This will work unless you query the result set from the database(using SELECT) in which case it would fail as it has not yet committed, give it a go.